# Can't transfer files between kubernetes pods running on different machines

Tags: kubernetes

For over a year I have my static website deployed in a Kubernetes cluster having only one node (basically respecting **Scenario 1** below).

These days I added another node to my cluster and everything works correctly, except one weird detail which blocked me publishing my website.

To exemplify, let's say I'm in `pod1`'s shell running on node `node1`.

#### Scenario 1. If my website is running in a pod on the same `node1`, then

```sh
// pod1

$ wget <static-website-pod-IP>:PORT/some-file.html
```

successfully fetches `some-file.html`.

#### Scenario 2. In contrast, if my website is running in a pod on `node2`, then the same command

```sh
// pod1

$ wget <static-website-pod-IP>:PORT/some-file.html
```

- successfully fetches `some-file.html` if the file has < ~1.4KB (empirically determined).
- blocks forever if `some-file.html` > ~ 1.4KB.

For the static website I tried multiple `nginx` versions and configs and also a python dummy server.

I also tested with Kubernetes latest v1.18 and latest v1.16.

Any idea why I just can't download larger files from pods running on a different node?

Comment: What CNI are you using? Have you checked if it's working properly? Can you connect from `pod1` on `node1` to `pod2` on `node2`? How did you setup your cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue starting from @anton-matsiuk 's hint.

The MTU used by the used network interface is 1450:

```
$ ip link show

...
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:00:00:53:4d:50 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
...
```

So the solution was to modify calico's `ConfigMap`'s default param `veth_mtu: "1440"` to `veth_mtu: "1430"`, according to [this table](https://docs.projectcalico.org/networking/mtu#determine-mtu-size).

Thank you, @anton-matsiuk.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is stuck at 1,4 kB, seems like your kubernetes networking plugin is misconfigured, as it transfers exactly one MSS/MTU.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a better way for copying files from pods would be using `kubectl cp`:

```
kubectl cp <file-spec-src> <file-spec-dest>
```

POD in a specific container

```
kubectl cp <file-spec-src> <file-spec-dest> -c <specific-container>
```

Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/bar
```

Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally

```
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the real life problem is that my website doesn't load in browser due to this behaviour. Ingress controller can't respond to external requests just because it doesn't receive the website files from the static web server if it's deployed on a different node than the ingress controller is running on.